# How to move a https website back to dev and access the admin?

Tags: redirect, https

I have a live WP site that uses https, when I move it back to a dev server that's http only I can't access the admin because it get's redirected to https. This only happens when I try to use the admin. Everything works fine in the front end.

So let's say I go to `mydevsite.com/wp-admin`. I get automatically redirect to `https://mydevsite.com/wp-admin`. What I am trying to find out is what's causing the browser to redirect my domain to a https. It's clearly something that remained from the live site. I just don't know what.

**My troubleshooting:**

My first guess is that I needed to update my .htacess file, but the file contains the default wordpress info only:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also checked functions.php to see if there was anything going on there, but I see nothing related to https.

I also checked the database and did a search for https. I have not found any entries that relate to my website. I specifically checked the `options` table. No https references there.

I also cleaned transients just in case.

**What are other things that I should check?**

Comment: Do a full find and replace on the database, this is a good script: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ and flush the permalinks.

Comment: I have done the database replacement. I know that I can flush the permalinks by visiting the settings page, but in this case I cannot visit that page. How would I go about flushing the permalinks?

Comment: check the `wp-config.php` file for `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN`

Comment: karpstrucking I just found out about define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); and then saw your comment. I changed it to false and it solved the issue. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

1 check that your wp-config.php file contains the following:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

2 if you're in a dev environment, then use wp-cli to run this:

```
wp search-replace 'https://example.com' 'http://example.com' --skip-columns=guid
```

Comment: Whith `--skip-columns=guid`, It does not perform substitution in the guid columns, but what is it usefull for please ?

Comment: Found [answer](http://torquemag.io/using-wp-cli-to-set-up-a-test-version-of-your-site/) : GUID entries are supposed to remain static for things like RSS readers